# Easy Slider doesn't work in page with "rtl" direction

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using the Easy Slider plugin.

http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

But when my page direction is right to left, it doesn't work.  Can you suggest a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work only in RTL (and not make it variable), it is quite easy.

In both JS and CSS, search for "left" and change it into "right", such as `margin-left` , `float:left`. And vice versa. Probably after that you have to do some minor tweaking, but most probably it will just work.

If you want to make it work both RTL and LTR, well then you have a different problem.

When the plugin loads, check the  direction of the plugin. Everywhere in JS where it says some direction, you'll have to add an if statement, changing the direction if you are in RTL.

In addition you'll have to override the values set in the CSS file if you are in RTL mode.

Answer (score 0):

you will need change in

css:

make float of slides to right in case of right to left page, and you can make a container class called rtl or ltr and make your code as following

```
.ltr .slide{float:left;}
.rtl .slide{float:right;}
```

js:

```
if ($("body").attr("dir") == "rtl")
    $('#slides').stop().animate({ marginRight: -positions[pos] + 'px' }, 450); or your code
else
    $('#slides').stop().animate({ marginLeft: -positions[pos] + 'px' }, 450); or your code
```

My Regards